# Why Use Lattice Under Siding

Tags: siding

I noticed several homes being constructed in my area lately where they're using a material over the building wrap and underneath the siding that looks like lattice.

Is that a relatively newer technique, and what is the benefit of doing so?  Is it for air flow to help keep things dry underneath?

I've seen it used under cedar shakes, board-and-batten, and other types of siding so I guess it's not specific to any one type of siding.

The location is Nova Scotia, Canada.  (coastal, humid in summer, dry in winter)

Comment: Your location probably matters, since it might be weather related or a local requirement.

Comment: Pictures would probably help, but it's likely something to help with drying, and intercepting water that gets through the siding so it drains away, rather than sitting trapped between the siding and the housewrap.

Answer (score 1):

In NZ, the standard has been for quite a few years that you have to have battens to space the exterior walls.  This is to allow the water to exit if it gets past the weatherboards.

So, the process is -

- You have timber framing,
- followed by building paper
- then battens (these have to be vertical so that the water can all the way down)
- finally weatherboards.